# Participial as adverbial?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, participial

1. ''Solve the questions **using what I have taught you**.''
2. ''He showed up **wearing a suit**.''
3. ''It is doing a nice job **covering up the broken chair**.''
4. ''I broke the law **getting you out of jail**.''
5. ''You were torturing yourself **figuring out how to tell her**.''

I can understand the meaning. But I don't understand why they are used without a preposition.

Are these participial used as adverbial? Or they are catenative verb?

Comment: No and no, I think. I parse them as adjectivally modifying the subject.

Answer (score 1):

They are all gerund-participial clauses, of course, and typically such clauses are indeed catenative complements (cf "I remember *telling you about it*").

But here, except for your second example, I'd say they were not catenatives, but adjuncts (adverbials) of means, thus part of clause structure. Notice that they describe how the events in the matrix clauses were performed. The inclusion of the expected "by" would have made them PPs, which typically introduces such adjuncts, (cf. "I got in *by breaking the door open*").

I see your second example as being a predicative adjunct, with "he" as predicand.

Comment: Hi there. 
What's the difference between:
''I broke the regulation drilling you out of the room.''
''I broke the regulation by drilling you out of the room.''
''I broke the regulation to drill you out of the room.''

Comment: @user140988 I'd treat all three as adjuncts (adverbials) of means. In each case, the adjunct answers the question 'how did I break the regulation'? Although the third example appears to be an adjunct of purpose, my knowingly breaking of the regulation was merely the outcome of my drilling you out, rather than the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Each grammar textbook (and its descendants) delivers its own dialect of terms and set of definitions, so results may vary among continents, decades and editions.

The venerable US handbook, *Warriner's English Grammar and Composition* (1969), states unequivocally,

> **3e. A *participle* is a verb form that is used as an adjective.**

If introduced by a preposition, verbals ending in -ing (as in the examples shown in the question, they'd be gerunds.

Even though a participial phrase may *look* like it wants to be an adverb, under the rules of Warriner (and the horde he rides with) it's just not so.

Adding prepositions to some of these might make good sense, but doing so would alter the grammatical construction a bit.

```
''Solve the questions ***by***using what I have taught you.''
''  turns the phrase into a gerund, which serves as the preposition's
''  object.  The phrase can then be construed as an adverb. If it's
''  that important to you...
```

Comment: Hi there. 
What's the difference between:
''I broke the regulation drilling you out of the room.''
''I broke the regulation by drilling you out of the room.''
''I broke the regulation to drill you out of the room.''

Comment: @user140988 I noticed that you asked the same question today on another grammar website!

Comment: This is a poor treatment; 'the window was [already] broken when we arrived there' and 'the window was broken [by the hail] during our stay there' show very different usages.